# Transform XML using Powershell - what is the equivalent of this Sed command?

Tags: powershell

I've got the following XML snippet:

> ```
> <simpleType name="StatusType">
>   <restriction base="integer">
>     <enumeration value="1">
>       <annotation>
>         <documentation>Proposed</documentation>
>       </annotation>
>     </enumeration>
>     <enumeration value="2">
>       <annotation>
>         <documentation>In Use</documentation>
>       </annotation>
>     </enumeration>
>   </restriction>
> </simpleType>
> ```

Which I want to transform into:

> ```
> <simpleType name="StatusType">
>   <restriction base="integer">
>       <enumeration value="1" id="Proposed"/>
>       <enumeration value="2" id="In Use"/>
>   </restriction>
> </simpleType>
> ```

I can do this on Linux using Sed as follows:

```
cat input_file.xml | sed -e '/<enumeration.*[^\/]>/{N;N;N;N;s/\r*\n[ \t]*//g;s/><annotation><documentation>/ id="/;s/<\/documentation><\/annotation><\/enumeration/"\//}'>output_file.xml
```

I'd like to achieve the same result on Windows - I could try a Windows port of Sed, but I'd rather use something like Powershell. 
Any ideas how I can achieve this in Powershell?  Get-Content has a replace function which looks useful - I can do a very basis replace as follows:

```
Get-Content input_file.xml | %{ $_ -replace "enumeration", "replacement_text" }
```

But I haven't a clue where to go next with it.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated, 
John

Comment: Well, since you seem to be okay with doing the replace a regex-way, you could just do `(Get-Content .\data.xml -Raw) -replace '(?s)(<enumeration value="[^"]*")[^>]*>.*?<documentation>([^<]*)</documentation>.*?</enumeration>', '$1 id="$2"/>'`. If you want to feel a little extra familiarity (or just want to feel a little feline), you could use the `cat` alias instead of `Get-Content`.

Comment: Excellent, that works for me, thanks for taking the time to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for a sed equivalent but there's an API for manipulating XML and I have to believe that is much safer that using regex on XML.  Here's one way to do this:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
<simpleType name="StatusType">
  <restriction base="integer">
    <enumeration value="1">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>Proposed</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </enumeration>
    <enumeration value="2">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>In Use</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </enumeration>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
'@

foreach ($enum in $xml.simpleType.restriction.enumeration) {
    [void]$enum.SetAttribute('id', $enum.annotation.documentation.Trim())
    [void]$enum.RemoveChild($enum.annotation)
    $enum.IsEmpty = $true
}

$xml | Format-Xml
```

Outputs:

```
<simpleType name="StatusType">
  <restriction base="integer">
    <enumeration value="1" id="Proposed" />
    <enumeration value="2" id="In Use" />
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

BTW `Format-Xml` is a command from the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com) module.  You can also just use the `Save()` method e.g.:

```
$xml.Save("C:\foo.xml")
```

Comment: Looks good, I might go with this method or the one below to avoid using regex.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
$Text = 
@'
<simpleType name="StatusType">
  <restriction base="integer">
    <enumeration value="1">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>Proposed</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </enumeration>
    <enumeration value="2">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>In Use</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </enumeration>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
'@

$regex = 
@'
(?ms)<simpleType name="StatusType">
  <restriction base="integer">
    <enumeration value="(\d+)">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>Proposed</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </enumeration>
    <enumeration value="(\d+)">
      <annotation>
        <documentation>In Use</documentation>
      </annotation>
    </enumeration>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
'@

if ($Text -match $regex)
{
@'
<simpleType name="StatusType">
  <restriction base="integer">
      <enumeration value="{0}" id="Proposed"/>
      <enumeration value="{1}" id="In Use"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
'@ -f $Matches[1,2]
}

<simpleType name="StatusType">
  <restriction base="integer">
      <enumeration value="1" id="Proposed"/>
      <enumeration value="2" id="In Use"/>
  </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

It's not exactly succinct, but it's intuitive and easy to maintain for the next guy that inherits it.

Comment: Nice solution, lots of options here for me to think about.